# Snap.svg traversing element tree

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I want to build SVG manipulation UI with Snap.svg, not as a send-alone, but with a server-side graphics package.

I need Snap.svg to load an external svg file, analyze its structure, define some event listeners to some of its elements (based on the analysis) and make some changes.

I noticed that the children of an element contain more than just the elements defined by the XML tree. So, a simple traversal of the children would not work.

Alternatively, the .selectAll method assumes advance knowledge of the svg structure.

There can be workaround to these, of course, but I am wondering if I am missing another more natural way of traversing the structure.

Comment: Why does a selectAll assume advance knowledge ?

Comment: Which do you prefer to use to load the svg file: Snap.load() or Snap.ajax()?

Comment: About selectAll: my understanding is that it searches based on the type or attribute of the elements. To be able to use this for a breath-first traversal of the tree (for example) you need to assume that the tree structure is somehow encoded in the attributes. 

About load() vs ajax() i don't care. load() is just a call to ajax(), anyways. Is there something I can do with ajax to make, at parse time, the children field to reflect the tree structure?

Comment: I think I see what the problem is. The .children() function is inherited from the Web API for node. As a result, it contains noise form the whites spaces of the SVG. In seams, Snap.svg needs some methods for accessing the proper svg children of an element. I will write a plugin to do that and will posted here. (Unless the functionality already exits, but I am missing it.)

Comment: Are you sure you need to do it that way? I can't fully tell what you are trying to do so I may be off track, but for example I did this http://svg.dabbles.info/snaptut-loadselect-move a long time ago, which lets you click on any element (N will rotate through any layered group elements), and drag it, then it will animate it.

Comment: @Ian So, the idea is to have a single even handler on the entire SVG, and then decide what to do based on what the local target is. (Will this work with mouseover and mouseout events?) This is interesting!

Comment: That would be my approach, but as every the devil is in the detail as to whether that would be suitable for your case :).

Answer (score 0):

I included an example below that calls an svg file via Snap.ajax(). It shows two SVG drawings. It places the response as single fragment in drawing **Fragment SVG**. It also allows XML methods to access/edit individual elements, and adds element fragments into the other drawing **XML SVG**.

Does this help?

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Snap.ajax()</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://svgDiscovery.com/_SNP/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload=loadXML()>
This loads an .svg file via Snap.ajax(). It places the response as single fragment in <b>Fragment SVG</b>. It also allows XML methods to access/edit individual elements, and adds element fragments into <b>XML SVG</b>.

 <center>
 <b>Fragment SVG</b>
 <div id=fragDiv style='border:1px solid black;width:500px;height:500px'>
<svg id=fragSVG width=500 height=500 ></svg>
 </div>
  <b>XML SVG</b>
 <div id=xmlDiv style='border:1px solid black;width:500px;height:500px'>
<svg id=xmlSVG width=500 height=500 ></svg>
 </div>
</center>
<script>
 var SNPsvgFrag = Snap("#fragSVG");
 var SNPsvgXML = Snap("#xmlSVG");


//---onload---
function loadXML()
{
    var svgFile="http://svgDiscovery.com/SVGFiles/Logo.svg"

    var xml=Snap.ajax(svgFile,function()
    {
        //---insert as one fragment---
        var xmlString=xml.responseText
        var fragment=Snap.fragment(xmlString)
        SNPsvgFrag.append(fragment)

        //---DOMParser---
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        var XMLdoc=parser.parseFromString(xmlString,"text/xml").documentElement;

        for(var k=0;k<XMLdoc.childNodes.length;k++)
        {
            var elem=XMLdoc.childNodes.item(k)

            console.log(elem.nodeName)

            if(elem.nodeName=="circle")
                elem.setAttribute("fill","red")

            //---each element inserted as a fragment---
            var elemString=new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(elem)

            var elemFrag=Snap.fragment(elemString)
            SNPsvgXML.append(elemFrag)
        }
    })
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! My goal is to manipulate the svg code entirely through the abstraction of the Snap.svg framework. Conceptually, I want to think of the task as geometry+attributes+behavior that happens to be encoded in SVG, rather than, XML that happens to encode geometry. I want to mirror the logical organization of the server-side vector engine so that communication can be simplified, and the project can be more scalable.  The best solution I have found so far is to get the children of an element and filter out the ones that should not be there, such as elements of type "#text". This is not elegant.

Comment: @Vakarelov Typically 'machine coded' svg does not include the #text element. i.e., it's all on a single line. I'm looking forward to you solving this app, and posting it here. Which server are you using?

Comment: indeed, one can overcome the problem that way, but this is not robust. I'm studying the snap.svg code and I'll see want is a good way to create a better geometry abstraction layer.  About the server-side, it is a proprietary  php-based vector graphics engine i am writing.